Action movie about money debt
I don't remember much from the movie because it has been at least 5 years since I saw it.
There was an older business man, maybe 60 years old, he was bald and sometimes wore a hat. In one scene he gets beaten up with a golf club.
The key scene I remember, though, is when they interrogate a guy that is tied to a chair. The chair hangs on a rope over a fish tank with piranhas or some other crazy fish that can eat people. The entire scene is in some kind of old factory building.

Can you guess the decade of the movie, was it new when you saw it 5 years ago? There are various movie with piranhas as threat, often old movies used that, like Bond-movies in the 60s or 70s (e.G.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-YGQP6-ftc). Hollywood movie or more like independend film?

no the movie is around  5 to 10 years old. and its not about piranhas. its about some business men and buildings. they just use piranhas as punishment in this one scene

I am quite sure you mean the move Rock N Rolla (2008) by Guy Ritchie.

In London, the British mob boss Lenny Cole (Tom Wilkinson) rules the
  growing real estate business using a corrupt Councillor (Jimi Mistry)
  for the bureaucratic services and his henchman Archy (Mark Strong) for
  the dirty work. A billionaire Russian businessman, Uri Omovich (Karel
  Roden), plans a crooked land deal, and London's crooks all want a
  piece of it. Other key players include the underhand accountant Stella
  (Thandie Newton) and ambitious small-time crook One-Two (Gerard
  Butler) leading a group called the "Wild Bunch" which includes Mumbles
  (Idris Elba) and Handsome Bob (Tom Hardy).
Lenny charges Uri €7,000,000 for the crooked deal; Uri has his
  accountant Stella find funds. Uri lends his lucky painting to Lenny as
  a sign of friendship. Stella, however, double-crosses Uri and tips off
  the Wild Bunch to steal the money, while the painting is stolen from
  Lenny's wall by his junkie rocker stepson Johnny Quid (Toby Kebbell),
  who disappears. Lenny and Archy coerce his former managers Mickey
  (Chris "Ludacris" Bridges) and Roman (Jeremy Piven) into tracking down
  Johnny. Handsome Bob also gets close to a lawyer who has information
  on a prevalent undercover informer in their criminal circle.
After Uri's money is stolen by the Wild Bunch a second time, his
  assistant Victor begins to suspect that it is Lenny who has been
  stealing the money and purposely keeping Uri's painting from him to
  resell it. This theory enrages Uri, who lures Lenny to a private golf
  game in order to break his leg, warning him to return his painting
  without delay.

You can see the beating with Golf club scene here (at 1:40):



About the chair and drowning scene, I do not remember this scene exactly (also saw the movie more then 5 years ago), but I am sure there was a scene like that in the movie: 

Archy orders Lenny's men to free the Wild Bunch and has Lenny drowned
  and fed to crayfish.

Did not find a video for the scene,  but you can see a part of it in the trailer at 0:25:




awesome. you made my day

"Speed Racer" (2008)
"A hole breaks in the side of a fish tank, a man is forced to put his finger in the hole, and piranhas swarm to his finger (we hear him scream and see him flailing, we see the water turn red and bubble and we see the man later with a bloody bandage where his finger used to be)"




looks like an awesome movie but sadly that is not the one i was searching for
